# Glade catalog picks wrong version of glib module

Tags: python, pygtk, glib, glade

On Fedora 16, I have a catalog library of widgets that I wish to load into glade.  Normally, this should be easy but since I have different versions of glib and gobject installed, the following error occurs:

```
; GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=./Components GLADE_MODULE_PATH=. glade fubar.glade

(glade:25069): GladeUI-PYTHON-WARNING **: Error initializing Python interpreter: could not import pygobject

(glade:25069): GladeUI-PYTHON-WARNING **: Unable to load pygobject module >= 2.90.0, please make sure it is in python's path (sys.path). (use PYTHONPATH env variable to specify non default paths)
could not import gobject (version mismatch, 2.90.0 is required, found 3.0.3)
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=./Components GLADE_MODULE_PATH=. glade
```

Is there a way to force a version of gobject?  Currently, I have this installed:

```
; yum list installed | grep pygobject
pygobject2.x86_64                      2.28.6-2.fc16                 @anaconda-0
pygobject2-codegen.x86_64              2.28.6-2.fc16                 @fedora    
pygobject2-devel.x86_64                2.28.6-2.fc16                 @fedora    
pygobject2-doc.x86_64                  2.28.6-2.fc16                 @fedora    
pygobject3.x86_64                      3.0.3-1.fc16                  @updates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. The problem is that the version check is wrong, *pyobject3* is just fine for the glade Python plugin. Patch is here:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706304. I don't know any fix other than recompiling glade, though.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises when using 3.10 (gtk3) instead of 3.8 (gtk2).

Comment: While this is true, vbraun's answer is better!